# Confused about Node, NPM, Bower, and using it for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bower

I'm trying to learn the latest technologies for web development. I already know HTML, JS, CSS, and server side programming. But I don't understand where `Nodejs`, `npm`, and `Bower` come in.

I want to create a new project. So I created a folder for it. Then I wanted to use bootstrap. So I ran `bower install bootstrap`. Now I have bootstrap installed in a folder called `bower_components`. Does this mean, if I want to import Bootstrap, I have to add it like this?:

```
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or am I missing something. I honestly don't know where to start with these package managers.

Comment: Now your next step is to learn to use `gulp.js` and to make gulp do all your build steps. That would include copying over bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css and all the other css into, say, `public/css`, and do all the JS and CSS minification and concatenation and make your public/ folder contain something like 6 files (out of 150 that you work with in the project) which you would use for production deployment :)

Comment: @Zlatko Interesting... Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`bower` - for installing client-side libraries/ modules( e.g: jquery, bootstrap, angular etc.), module details generally put in `bower.json` of project root folder

`npm` - for installing server-side modules (express, crypto, socket.io, etc.), module details generally put in `package.json` of project root folder.

In general, the things you install using `npm` get stored in the folder `node_modules` and `bower` puts it in `bower_components`,

I am assuming you are using `express` module on `node.js` server. When you add a line like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/bower_components'));
```

Now your HTML files, can use the bower components as

```
<link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Another option is to edit `.bowerrc` and specify where the downloaded bower modules must be put...

Comment: amazing, this is what I looking for! thanks for great answer.